# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'A'

Tags: typescript, types

I have the following code snippet that does not compile:

```
interface A {
    a: string
}

export type SessionSsrProps<T> = Record<string, T> & {
    signOutUrl: string
}

const x: SessionSsrProps<A> = {
    x: {
        a: "Hello"
    },
    signOutUrl: "Hello"
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'A'
```

What am I doing wrong?

I also tried:

```
interface SessionSsrProps<T> {
    [key:string]: T
    signOutUrl: string
}
```

and the compiler complains:

```
Property 'signOutUrl' of type 'string' is not assignable to string index type 'T'.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "return type" in this bit? _"should allow defining any properties with type String and return type is constrained with type T"_

Comment: Sorry, I only want to know why it is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't say confidently whether what you're doing is possible or not, but it's likely that it is not.

Both your attempts fail because you're describing an impossible type: a record with zero or more keys whose values are all of type `T`, AND also there is a key `signOutUrl` with a value of type `string`. This requires `signOutUrl` to satisfy both `string & T`, which is unresolvable given that `T` does not extend `string`.

What you want to express is a record with zero or more keys whose values are all of type `T`, **EXCEPT** the key `signOutUrl` which has a value of type `string`. I believe (but am not certain) that this is not currently expressible in TypeScript.